# Erro: 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint -MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela porém estou com um problema numa chave estrangeira, pelo menos é o que parece e é o que consegui entender nas minhas pesquisar.

Olhem o código por favor, o erro ocorre na ultima tabela.
(Achei vários posts similares mas tentei as sugestões e nada adiantou)

```
CREATE TABLE Professor(
    ra INT  NOT NULL 
    ,apelido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,nome VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
    ,email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
    ,celular CHAR(11) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pkra PRIMARY KEY (ra)
    ,CONSTRAINT uqapelido UNIQUE (apelido) 
    );

CREATE TABLE Curso(
    sigla VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL 
    ,nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pksigla PRIMARY KEY (sigla)
    ,CONSTRAINT uqnome UNIQUE (nome)
    );

CREATE TABLE GradeCurricular(
    sigla_curso VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
    ,ano SMALLINT NOT NULL
    ,semestre CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT fksigla_curso FOREIGN KEY (sigla_curso) REFERENCES Curso (sigla) 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (sigla_curso,ano,semestre)
);

CREATE TABLE Periodo(
    sigla_curso VARCHAR(5)
    ,ano_grade SMALLINT
    ,semestre_grade CHAR (1) 
    ,numero TINYINT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_sigla_curso FOREIGN KEY (sigla_curso) REFERENCES GradeCurricular (sigla_curso)
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_ano_grade FOREIGN KEY (ano_grade) REFERENCES GradeCurricular (ano)
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_semestre_grade FOREIGN KEY (semestre_grade) REFERENCES GradeCurricular (semestre)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (sigla_curso,ano_grade,semestre_grade,numero)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use essa declaração para a tabela Periodo:

```
CREATE TABLE Periodo(
    sigla_curso VARCHAR(5)
    ,ano_grade SMALLINT
    ,semestre_grade CHAR (1) 
    ,numero TINYINT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_sigla_curso FOREIGN KEY (sigla_curso, ano_grade, semestre_grade) REFERENCES GradeCurricular (sigla_curso, ano, semestre)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (sigla_curso,ano_grade,semestre_grade,numero)
);
```

Comment: Opaa Man, Funcionou!!! Obrigado, passei o dia todo tentando várias coisas aqui e sem sucesso rs.